# How to put tikzpicture nicely between paragraphs?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to put my tikzpicture nicely between paragraphs. How do I do that? I do not want  to put it in a picture environment because than there is extra space underneath.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\unframedsolutions
%\printanswers
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\newgeometry{left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}


Line above tikzpicture.

\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=5mm]
\path node[rectangle,draw=green,fill=green!8,inner sep=.70cm] {\parbox{\textwidth-1.4cm-\fboxrule}{

\question[2] What is the first question?
\begin{solutionorlines}[4cm]
This box is smaller than when the solutions are not printed. How do I make this the same dimension as when answers are not printed?
\end{solutionorlines}
}};
\end{tikzpicture}

Line under tikzpicture. I don't want this. I want the tikzpicture between paragraphs.

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: to put a tikzpicture between _paragraphs_ you do what you did, but the problem here is that the `questions` environment is only expecting `\question` and you have plain paragraphs and a picture and `\question` nested in a parbox, none of which are expected as far as I can see looking at the code of `exam.cls`

Comment: I use it for student work sheets. Some alternatives than? You know a way by looking at the exam.cls to make the height of the box the same with lines or without lines (solution printed or solution not printed have the same height of box)?

Comment: Try adding a new line \\ after `Line above tikzpicture`. Is this what you want?

Comment: It works but again I have more space between "Line under tikzpicture" and the picture above then between "Line above tikzpicture" and the picture below. How to adjust that?

Comment: @Dirk11 I may look later (or I may not, it's christmas:-), but there are plenty of people on site who know exam class and can probably answer far more easily:-)

Comment: Your example contains only one `tikzpicture`, could show a more complete example?

Comment: If you want to put your quastion in a frame, you can check the `mdframed` package. It can use TikZ to draw the frames. But in your example there is something strange, I agree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drawing a colored box is my catchword for offering a `tcolorbox` as solution. The exact white space dimension can be set with `before skip` and `after skip`. Since you want it to be the same, you can also use `beforeafter skip`. I use two boxes below: The first one is the normal one, the second one just to show the distance settings.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\unframedsolutions
%\printanswers
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newgeometry{left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm}

\newtcolorbox{greenbox}[1][]{%
  size=fbox,
  arc=5mm,
  boxsep=0.7cm,
  %boxsep=\fboxsep,% uncommented to use \fboxsep
  colframe=green,
  colback=green!8,
  beforeafter skip=3mm,% <--- Space setting before and after
  #1%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

Line above tikzpicture.

\begin{greenbox}
  \question[2] What is the first question?
  \begin{solutionorlines}[4cm]
  This box is smaller than when the solutions are not printed. How do I make this the same dimension as when answers are not printed?
  \end{solutionorlines}
\end{greenbox}

Line under tikzpicture. I don't want this. I want the tikzpicture between paragraphs.

Line above tikzpicture.

\begin{greenbox}[beforeafter skip=0mm]
  \question[2] What is the first question?
  \begin{solutionorlines}[4cm]
  This box is smaller than when the solutions are not printed. How do I make this the same dimension as when answers are not printed?
  \end{solutionorlines}
\end{greenbox}

Line under tikzpicture. I don't want this. I want the tikzpicture between paragraphs.

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Genius! \the\boxsep doesn't work. How do I show this (and use it to calculate)?

Comment: @Dirk11 You could e.g. use `boxsep=\fboxsep`. Then, you can use `\fboxsep` for calculations (see my updated answer).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the `exam` class, but it seems that inside `questions` environment, all paragraphs are treted differently. You can add newline without adding paragraphe break.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\unframedsolutions
%\printanswers
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\newgeometry{left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

Line above tikzpicture.\\[1em]
\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=5mm]
\path node[rectangle,draw=green,fill=green!8,inner sep=.70cm] {
  \parbox{\textwidth-1.4cm-\fboxrule}{
    \question[2] What is the first question?
    \begin{solutionorlines}[4cm]
    This box is smaller than when the solutions are not printed. How do I make this the same dimension as when answers are not printed?
    \end{solutionorlines}
  }};
\end{tikzpicture}\\[1em]
Line under tikzpicture. I don't want this. I want the tikzpicture between paragraphs.

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

**NOTE:** You can check `mdframed` package if you want to put questions in frames.

[image]

Comment: Look really close, the white space between tikzpic and "Line above tikzpicture" and the white space between tikzpic and "Line under tikzpicture" are different.

Comment: @Dirk11 for this reason I have put `\\[1em]`. You can adjust the space before and after your tikz picture by changing `1em` to some other value.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete solution, since the spacing is slightly off, and the answer width is too large. No time to make the final adjustments. Others can edit this answer or use it as a starting point:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\unframedsolutions
\printanswers % or commented out for lines
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\newgeometry{left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question[2] What is the first question?
\begin{solutionorlines}[4cm]
\begin{minipage}[t][4cm]{\textwidth}This box is smaller than when the solutions are not printed. How do I make this the same dimension as when answers are not printed?\end{minipage}
\end{solutionorlines}
\question[2] What is the second question?
\begin{solutionorlines}[4cm]
\begin{minipage}[t][4cm]{\textwidth} This box is smaller than when the solutions are not printed. How do I make this the same dimension as when answers are not printed?\end{minipage}
\end{solutionorlines}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]