# Exam class: same space solution vs. no solution

Tags: exam

In exam class, by inserting a fixed minipage same size of your answerslines for students you create the same space when answers are printed or when answers are not printed. How come the depth is still different? Don't tell me to use \vspace.[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\unframedsolutions

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\newgeometry{left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm}

\newtcolorbox{greenbox}[1][]{%
  size=fbox,
  arc=5mm,
  boxsep=0.7cm,
  colframe=green,
  colback=green!8,
  beforeafter skip=5mm,% <--- Space setting before and after
  #1%
}

%\printanswers
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}


\begin{greenbox}
  \question[2] What is the first question?
  \begin{solutionorlines}[4cm]               %heidht no answers=4cm
  \begin{minipage}[t][4cm]{\textwidth-1.4cm} %height answers =4cm
   The depth of this box is larger when answers are printed compared to answers not printed. How do I make "answers" and "no answers" the same dimension?
   \end{minipage}
  \end{solutionorlines}
\end{greenbox}%


\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I do not think that this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219332/how-to-put-tikzpicture-nicely-between-paragraphs. It uses the same example, but the old question was about spacing before and after a colored box. This one is about spacing in the solution part of the `exam` class.

Comment: I have looked through the exam class manual and to the best of my knowledge there is no way to achieve this except to use \vspace command(s) after each solution.

Answer (score 4):

I think the `exam` class itself should provide a solution for the question, but I am not familiar enough with it to know if it's a configuration problem.

To circumvent the problem, you could embed the the solution part with another `minipage`. The following code always uses the same amount of space for answers and lines:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\unframedsolutions

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\newgeometry{left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm}

\newtcolorbox{greenbox}[1][]{%
  size=fbox,
  arc=5mm,
  boxsep=0.7cm,
  colframe=green,
  colback=green!8,
  beforeafter skip=5mm,% <--- Space setting before and after
  #1%
}

%\printanswers
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}


\begin{greenbox}
  \question[2] What is the first question?
  \par\begin{minipage}[t][4cm]{\linewidth} %height answers =4cm
    \begin{solutionorlines}[4cm]               %heidht no answers=4cm
    \begin{minipage}[t][4cm]{\linewidth-1.9cm} %height answers =4cm
     The depth of this box is larger when answers are printed compared to answers not printed. How do I make "answers" and "no answers" the same dimension?
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{solutionorlines}
  \end{minipage}
\end{greenbox}%


\end{questions}

\end{document}
```